# Using a Factory to create a class, which is used in another class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have the following situation:

Factory class implementation:

```
class FactoryClassA {
    public:
        FactoryClassA(){};
        ~FactoryClassA(){};

        ClassA create(double a, double b) {
            return ClassA;
        };
};
```

ClassA implementation:

```
class ClassA {
    friend class FactoryClassA
    ~FactoryClassA() {}
    private:
        ClassA(double a = 0, double b = 0)
        {
            a(a),
            b(b)
        };
        double a;
        double b;
};
```

OtherClass implementation:

```
class OtherClass {
    public:
        OtherClass() {
            ClassFactory myClassAFactory;
            aClassA = myClassAFactory.create();
        }
        ~OtherClass() {};

    private:
        aClassA;
};
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Because in the (empty) member initializer list of `OtherClass`, the empty constructor of `ClassA` is called, which does not exist.

The reason why I made the constructor of `ClassA` `private`, is that I want the user to only create objects of `ClassA` through the `FactoryClassA`.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Please fix your code: indent it and add `;`

Comment: 1. You don't put the destructor for FactoryClassA in another class. 2. ClassFactory is undefined. 3. `friend` should be outside the braces.

Comment: I strongly suggest you start with compilable code. Your code as posted has multiple syntaxic errors.

Comment: Edit: 3. friendly members are in the braces. Are you trying to make the destruct0r available to ClassA?

Comment: Not your real code because it contains multiple huge syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `create()` should have a return type:

```
ClassA create(double a, double b) {
   return {a, b};
}
```

I am not going through all the other syntactic bugs. Please fix them, because others might find your question when they search for answers. Please make it easy for them to understand your question.

This has to be in your code after `ClassA` has been defined, because the compiler has to know the size of a `ClassA` object as well as the constructor to use.

Second, just initialize your members before the constructor body:

```
OtherClass() :
   aClassA{ClassFactory{}.create(0.0, 0.0)}
{}
```

You might prefer to have `create()` as a static member function of `ClassFactory`. Then the `OtherClass` constructor looks like this:

```
OtherClass() :
   aClassA{ClassFactory::create(0.0, 0.0)}
{}
```

That is more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This code is full of small errors, that make it unuseable. First syntax for member initialization for a class is :

```
class A {
    A(x, y): m_a(x) { ... }
    ...
}
```

and class declaration are statements so they need the final `;`

Next, the dtor for a class must be public if you want to be able to use temporary objects.

The default values should not be in `ClassA` ctor but on `create` factory method.

Finally, you should use a static factory in OtherClass, no need to create a new factory for each object.

Code becomes:

```
class FactoryClassA;

class ClassA {
public:
    friend class FactoryClassA;
    ~ClassA(){}
private:
    ClassA(double a, double b):a(a),b(b){}
    double a;
    double b;
};

class FactoryClassA {
public:
    FactoryClassA(){}
    ~FactoryClassA(){}

    ClassA create(double a = 0, double b = 0) {
        return ClassA(a, b);
    }
};

class OtherClass {
public:
    OtherClass(): aClassA(myClassAFactory.create()){}
    ~OtherClass(){}

private:
    static FactoryClassA myClassAFactory;
    ClassA aClassA;

};

FactoryClassA OtherClass::myClassAFactory;
```

Not far from original one, but this ones compiles...